# Seat Leon FR TDi 170 injector recall - affected cars

Tags: maintenance, parts, performance

I am looking at purchasing a 58 plate (late 2008) Seat Leon FR TDi 170. I am aware of the injector recall, however I would like to know for how long the problematic injectors were a problem for?

The posts I read all reference 06, 56, 07 models...I am looking at a 58 - are they still affected?

The car I am looking at has 95,000 miles on the clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seat UK support have confirmed that the car *is* included in the recall and four new injectors will be replaced free of charge.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way is probably to phone a Seat dealer and ask. Usually recalls are "Any vehicle with a VIN in the range X to Y" - so all you need to do is find that range and make sure the car you're looking at isn't in it...

The [VOSA Database](http://www.vosa.gov.uk/vosa/apps/recalls/default.asp) also has a list of all official recalls on UK market cars or parts, and doesn't list any for a 2008 Leon.

Comment: Thanks. I'm surprised that there is nothing on the VOSA database for the injector recall. There is plenty on Google about it, unfortunately nothing about what cars are affected. [Check HERE](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=seat+leon+fr+injector+recall&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)